# Extract first few alphabets before numbers and skip the rest

Tags: sql, regex, impala, hue

I have a strange requirement where we want to extract first few alphabets in a string and skip the rest where there can be combination of alphabets and numbers. 
e.g. 
Text

```
1.  aaaa bbbb ccc 00110011 ddd eee ff 00 99 
2.  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb 0123 azbe 999999999999999  
3.  zfsfzzzzzzzzzz asasas 111 3333333 xxysys ddddd  9090909  
4.  Returns the nth field within a delimited string 5555555555 99999999
```

Output

```
1.  aaaa bbbb ccc 
2.  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb 
3.  zfsfzzzzzzzzzz asasas 
4.  Returns the nth field within a delimited string
```

We are using Hue/Impala and would like to extract all alphabets in first characters or all left characters before a number string starts.

Thank you

Comment: How about [`^[^0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/dl8dKR/1) or [`^[^0-9]+[[:>:]]`](https://regex101.com/r/dl8dKR/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `regexp_extract()` should work:

```
select regexp_extract(col, '^[a-zA-Z ]+', 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use regex (since you put it in as a tag) you can use the following to (match until numeric):

```
^[^0-9]*
```

Comment: Or ^[a-z|A-Z| ]* for the other way around